# Azure VS2010 packaging error - "Access to the path 'foo.dll' is denied"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

When packaging my VS 2010 Azure cloud project, I get the following error in the output window:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Windows Azure Tools\1.6\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(2886,5): error : Access to the path 'C:\Users\rpotter\AppData\Local\Temp\3rbnncvy.lcl\roles\Bus\approot\Foo.dll' is denied.

The cloud project builds fine, but fails at the packaging stage. This is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, VS2010 x86, Azure SDK 1.7. I have recently changed some namespaces and folder structures, but as the solution builds ok, I do not think this is related. I have created a new cloud project from scratch, and still suffer from the error. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution. One of the C# library projects (not a web/worker role) had a reference in the .csproj to the old folder structure. This was only manifesting itself at package-time and not compile-time. Case closed.

Comment: i'm having same issue can you describe bit further what do you mean by folder structure? also any heads up what do's/don'ts precisely?

Comment: From memory (3 years ago!), I had changed the folder structure on disk, so that the entire solution was in a different location. I checked that all the references were working and that it built as expected. And it did. However, there is some metadata in the .csproj files that points to folders that is not used at compile time, only at packaging time. I just edited this with Notepad++. That is all I can remember about it. HTH.

Comment: thank you, actually it was more related to dll reference, multiple reference points for one dll across different projects.